# Finding out which disk is causing block errors in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I am using Windows.
In `Event viewer` I see errors like this:

```
Message: Faulty block in device \Device\Harddisk1\DR1
Source: Disk
Code: 7
```

I have 2 disks. One is SSD and other HDD. How can I find out which of them is causing these errors?

I have checked drive properties from `Disk management` but cannot find path like this. I see `Disk0` and `Disk1` there. Should I assume that `Disk1` is same as `Harddisk1` in device path?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to visit computer management >> storage >> disk management. You need to run computer management with admin permissions, so log-in as admin or type it in the search box after opening start menu and right click >> Run as admin

If there are bad blocks, it shouldn't be listed as a disk without failures.

Without knowing your intentions I would take a guess and say you have your OS on the SSD, which means Disk 0. Seems like the HDD. Only as a guess.

Comment: Disk 0 is HDD that acts as storage disk. Disk 1 is SSD with OS. (Originally I had only HDD and moved the OS to SSD when I got it.) In `Disk management` both disks as shown as `Healthy`.